# Convert CSV to JSON arrays of objects in R

Tags: r, arrays, json, csv

I have csv file that looks like what you see below. I want to convert it into a JSON format but in a hierarhical way based on the `ew_id` column such that for each unique `ew_id` I will have a new array of objects (see example below). I also want to group `fil1` thru `fil5` as `fillers` in my JSON-formatted variable.

| sub_num | cons_r | sus_r | sus | fil1 | fil2 | fil3 | fil4 | fil5 | perp | ew_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 147 | W | 1 | 57 | 77 | 60 | 67 | 32 | 76 | 89 | 1 |
| 55 | B | 2 | 177 | 111 | 148 | 145 | 113 | 141 | 193 | 1 |
| NA | R | 1 | 53 | 7 | 11 | 25 | 50 | 81 | 87 | 2 |
| NA | R | 2 | 150 | 124 | 120 | 157 | 178 | 164 | 188 | 2 |

So the JSON would ideally look like this:

```
let exp_info = [

 [{"ew_id": 1,
  "sub_num": 147,
  "cons_r": "W",
  "sus_r": 1,
  "sus": 57,
  "fillers": [77,60,67,32,76],
  "perp":89},

  {"ew_id":1,
   "sub_num":55,
   "cons_r": "B",
   "sus_r": 2,
   "sus": 177,
   "fillers": [111,148,145,113,141],
   "perp":193
   }],

[{"ew_id": 2,
  "sub_num": NA,
  "cons_r": "R",
  "sus_r": 1,
  "sus": 53,
  "fillers": [7,11,25,50,81],
  "perp":87},

  {"ew_id":2,
   "sub_num":NA,
   "cons_r": "R",
   "sus_r": 2,
   "sus": 150,
   "fillers": [124,120,157,178,164],
   "perp":188
   }]
];
```

I would appreciate any tips to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
tmp <- quux |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(fillers = list(c_across(matches("^fil[0-9]")))) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-matches("^fil[0-9]"))
split(tmp, tmp$ew_id) |>
  unname() |>
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
# [
#   [
#     {
#       "sub_num": 147,
#       "cons_r": "W",
#       "sus_r": 1,
#       "sus": 57,
#       "perp": 89,
#       "ew_id": 1,
#       "fillers": [77, 60, 67, 32, 76]
#     },
#     {
#       "sub_num": 55,
#       "cons_r": "B",
#       "sus_r": 2,
#       "sus": 177,
#       "perp": 193,
#       "ew_id": 1,
#       "fillers": [111, 148, 145, 113, 141]
#     }
#   ],
#   [
#     {
#       "cons_r": "R",
#       "sus_r": 1,
#       "sus": 53,
#       "perp": 87,
#       "ew_id": 2,
#       "fillers": [7, 11, 25, 50, 81]
#     },
#     {
#       "cons_r": "R",
#       "sus_r": 2,
#       "sus": 150,
#       "perp": 188,
#       "ew_id": 2,
#       "fillers": [124, 120, 157, 178, 164]
#     }
#   ]
# ]
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(sub_num = c(147L, 55L, NA, NA), cons_r = c("W", "B", "R", "R"), sus_r = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), sus = c(57L, 177L, 53L, 150L), fil1 = c(77L, 111L, 7L, 124L), fil2 = c(60L, 148L, 11L, 120L), fil3 = c(67L, 145L, 25L, 157L), fil4 = c(32L, 113L, 50L, 178L), fil5 = c(76L, 141L, 81L, 164L), perp = c(89L, 193L, 87L, 188L), ew_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```